# What's the noun for "extraordinary"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Maybe it's "extraordinarity"? However, the word only has [5000](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=extraordinarity) Google results.

Example sentence:

> Being a freak is not a good kind of __.

Comment: "... is not a good way to be exceptional."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **extraordinariness**
>   Noun The property or state of being extraordinary.
>   - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extraordinariness

Also see this ELU question:
 [What's a good word that means extraordinariness or exceptional-ness?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14552/whats-a-good-word-that-means-extraordinariness-or-exceptional-ness)

And just for the record the NGRAM shows *extraordinarity* virtually unused relative to *extraordinariness* :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say **Deviation**.  Dictionary.com defines the word as "departure from a standard or norm."  Since a deviation can be either positive or negative in nature, you're not being redundant when you call it "not a good kind of deviation."  Deviation also carries a sociological connotation, which might be a point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

**Extraordinaire** can be drafted into service, but use with caution.

http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/slideshows/people/alfred-nobel-life-of-an-extraordinaire/slideshow/23976481.cms

https://www.kcet.org/shows/artbound/peter-sprague-an-extraordinaire-from-the-land-of-extraordinary-guitarists

As a noun, it used to refer to a particular type of payment, and was also used as a shortened form of some job titles.

I have no problem with "a freak is not a good kind of extraordinaire."